# Blazor and customised bootstap

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5

I have been using Blazor for Dashboard like applications (for IT employees) recently, where functionality is crucial and "look and feel" is not as important. I use for example MudBlazor libabry for this and it works like a charm. I have been asked recently to built client facing application, where "look and feel" is crucial and client has already chosen customised Bootsrap ( https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=7340 ).

It looks nice and customer was even able to design his own html pages (not connected to back end). My task is now „just connect those pages to back end DB“ to display real data and enable end user to place and order (form saving data to DB).

I am struggling to use Blazor together with this Bootstrap. I assume that javascripts are not compatible, but I am wondering how experienced Blazor developer approaches such tasks.

Customers requirement is perfectly valid. Using „ready to use/nice look and feel“ Boostrap library makes perfect sense, but I am not able to deliver such web pages  due to the Blazor incompatibility.

I am able to prepare working web pages without „Blazor binding“ by ommitting
`<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`
Most of Space Boostrap functionality works then.

But without `blazor.server.js` data binding does not work obviously, which is a showstopper.

Is there any Booostraps list „tailored“ for Blazor similar to https://themes.getbootstrap.com/ ? I mean „predesigned“ fancy pages with „Shopping cart“, „Contact info“ etc. ? I am aware of Blazor libaries like MudBlazor, Telerik, Syncfusion ….

Comment: No, you won't find such list tailored for Blazor. The CSS and the layout are the same in Blazor and static html, so what would it be good for? You just replace the javascript components with some Blazor Components, but it will use your customized CSS.

In my blazor server side project, I'm using plain bootstrap with it's javascript and little of custom JS interop and it works just fine. You just need to be aware when blazor could override the changes to DOM made by bootstrap's javascript.

Comment: It all depends on what has been customized in Bootstrap and what JS functionality is being used.   You can take just the customized bootstrap css files with whatever Blazor UI you are designing and see what breaks/doesn't work.  Figure out why and write some component code to solve the problem.  You can use some Blazor Bootstrap libraries out there - Havit for example that sort out all the JS issues.  Use the source and apply your custom Bootstrap css.   You need to check with the supplier of the custom BS what custom JS is used.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis How do you check with BS vendor "what custom JS is used" ? I am afraid that I am not able to check it without "trial and error" approach.

Comment: I assumed the Bootstrap was customised by a design house.   If it's off the shelf then you're down to trial and error I'm afraid!